# Flutter create sqlite database helper to return only 1 String or any other single object type

Tags: sqlite, dart, flutter

Using sqlite in Android (java base) are quite simple. I can retrieve whether list of data, or just single data in such way using my custom database helper.

**i.e**:

```
    public String getLastNetPrintUrl() {
    String lastPrintUrl;
    String lastId = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NET_PRINT + " WHERE " + COL_NETPRINT_ID +
            " = (SELECT MAX(" + COL_NETPRINT_ID + ") FROM " + TABLE_NET_PRINT + ")";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(lastId, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        lastPrintUrl = cursor.getString(4);
    } else {
        lastPrintUrl = "";
    }
    db.close();
    return lastPrintUrl;
}
```

In above piece of code, I simply want to get the last recorded URL. Then in the activity, I can just call

```
String netPrintUrl = dbhelper.getLastNetPrintUrl();
```

How can I achieve the same goal using sqflite in Flutter?

What I've done so far,

```
  Future<String> getLastUrl() async {
var dbClient = await db;
String lastUrlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM device WHERE id = (SELECT MAX( id ) FROM device)';
var dbQuery = await dbClient.rawQuery(lastUrlQuery);
if (dbQuery.length > 0) {
  String lastUrl = dbQuery.first.values.toString();
  return lastUrl;
} else {
  return '192.168.11.17:7700';
}
```

}

But whenever I tried to call that method, just the same way, like

```
String lastUrl = dbhelper.getLastUrl;
```

Value type of Future can't be assigned to variable of type 'String';

I'm still pretty new to Flutter, and couldn't find any reference about my intention above. Any hints are appreciated.

***edit:**

That 'Device' table only contain 2 column, which is integer unique id, and  url (as text).

**edit:** *final part of code*

```
final _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
final _urlController = new TextEditingController();

DatabaseHelper dbhelper = DatabaseHelper();
String atiDeviceUrl;

Future getUrl() async{
  atiDeviceUrl = await dbhelper.getLastUrl();
  _urlController.text = atiDeviceUrl;
  print('atiDeviceUrl: $atiDeviceUrl');
}

@override
void initState() {
  getUrl();
  super.initState();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to familiarize yourself with [asynchronous programming](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures) in Dart.

When you call an asynchronous ([`async`](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures#async-await)) function such as your `dbhelper.getLastUrl()`, the function body doesn't actually get immediately executed.

Instead, a [`Future`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html) object is returned to you, and execution continues right back where you called the function. The asynchronous function will get executed at a later, indeterminate time. That's why you can't have a `String` as the result, but rather a `Future<String>`.

So, to actually get the `String` result of your function and do anything useful with it in synchronous code, you have to wait for the completion of the `Future` using [`Future.then()`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-async/Future/then.html). For example:

```dart
dbhelper.getLastUrl().then((final String lastURL) {
  print("The last URL was: $lastURL");
});
```

However, if you call `dbhelper.getLastUrl()` from another `async` function, and just add the keyword [`await`](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures#async-await), things look much simpler:

```dart
final String lastURL = await dbhelper.getLastUrl();
print("The last URL was: $lastURL");
```

Under the hood, this is essentially equivalent to the previous example, but Dart automagically generates the callback handler code for you.

Now, the good news is that if you need to call your `async` function from, for example, a button press callback handler, you can usually just add the magic `async` keyword to that callback function and everything is pretty easy. For example, try this:

```dart
RaisedButton(
  child: Text("Get the last URL"),
  onPressed: () async {
    final String lastURL = await dbhelper.getLastUrl();
    print("The last URL was: $lastURL");
  },
)
```

Comment: Ah, need to dive deeper with asynchronous in dart. Quite a nice hint.